# What is the probability of group cohesion while admitting people into a nightclub at random?

Tags: probability, distributions

A crowd of size $N$ outside a club is made up of $N/G$ groups of friends, for argument's sake, e.g. $G = 5$.

This is a fictitious setup… groups are usually differing in size outside nightclubs… but please ignore this and assume all groups are the same size: i.e. $G$.

The bouncer selects people to enter the nightclub at random, paying no notice of group cohesion.

After admitting $k$ individuals from the crowd, the bouncer stops admitting people.

Inside the club, the groups re-assemble.  Groups that were fully admitted are said to have "high cohesion", and groups where none were admitted are said to have "no cohesion".  I refer to the remnants of the groups which are now inside the nightclub as the "remnant groups".  Unlike the evenly sized groups at the beginning, inside the nightclub, these remnant groups will be of varying size.

Given the variables $N, G, k$, what is the distribution of remnant group sizes inside the night club?

## What I've Tried Already

I don't generally work with this kind of statistics, so I first tried to investigate the above problem by looking at a simpler one: groups of size $G = 2$.  In this case, the multinomial formula comes in handy:

$\frac{2^{n-2K}\frac{N}{2}! }{(n-2K)! K! (\frac{N}{2}-n+K)!}$

However, I'm failing to see how I can generalise the above when dealing with groups bigger than couples.

For small N, I was also able to exhaustively find the expected distribution of remnant group sizes:

```py
from itertools import combinations, permutations    
from tqdm import tqdm    
N = 20    
G = 5    
k = 5    
if N % G != 0: raise ValueError("N must be divisible by G")    
groups = sorted(list(range(20 // G)) * G)    
print(groups)    
dist = {}    
for i in tqdm(combinations(groups, k)):    
    s = set(i)    
    d = {}        
    for j in i: d[j] = d.get(j,0)+1    
    j = d.values()    
    d2 = {}    
    for k,v in d.items():    
        d2[v] = d2.get(v,0)+1    
    remnant_group_sizes = (tuple(sorted(d2.items())))    
    dist[remnant_group_sizes] = dist.get(remnant_group_sizes, 0) + 1    
dist2 = {}    
total_combinations = 0    
for row, count in dist.items():               
    print(row, ":", count)    
    for group_size, occurences in row:    
        dist2[group_size] = dist2.get(group_size, 0) + occurences * count    
        total_combinations += occurences * count    
for row, count in sorted(dist2.items()):    
    print(row, ":", count, count / total_combinations)
"""
OUTPUT
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
((5, 1),) : 4
((1, 1), (4, 1)) : 300
((2, 1), (3, 1)) : 1200
((1, 2), (3, 1)) : 3000
((1, 1), (2, 2)) : 6000
((1, 3), (2, 1)) : 5000
1 : 27300 0.5459563234941205
2 : 18200 0.36397088232941366
3 : 4200 0.08399328053755699
4 : 300 0.005999520038396928
5 : 4 7.999360051195904e-05
"""
```

Another thing I tried was to think of the problem on a individual level.  The bouncer knows she can only admit k, so she processes the crowd in the form of a queue, accepting individuals based on flipping an unfair coin with probability of success (heads) set to $k/N$.  This would basically be a binomial distribution, meaning I'd expect groups of size $S$ to occur ${G\choose{S}}(n/N)^S(1-n/N)^{G-S}$.  However, when I tested this out the distribution was somewhat off what I would have expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[I received the above idea from an answer under another question (linked)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/632820/what-is-the-probability-of-selecting-couples-from-a-waiting-room).

## (Updated) Answer

I came up with the below equation to describe the probability of $k$ *remnant groups* of size $g$, when admitting $n$ individuals from a population of $N/G$ groups of size $G$:
$
\frac{
{{G}\choose{g}}^k                                      
{\frac{N}{G}\choose{k}}
\left[                                              
{N-Gk\choose n-gk}      
+
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{                               
\min\left(         
\frac{n-gk}{g},
\frac{N-Gk}{G}
\right)
}
\left[-
{{G}\choose{g}}\right]^i                            
{\frac{N-Gk}{G}\choose i}
{N-Gk-Gi\choose {n-gk-gi}}
\right]
}{{N\choose n}}
$

If anyone knows of any other (more efficient) approaches than the above, please add an answer.

Comment: * In your sequential $k/N$ sampling simulation, did you ensure at least and at most $k$ were selected?
* "expect groups of size S to occur ... [*times*?]"
* I think it would help to follow an "argument from induction" approach, 2 is the couples problem, write 3. Don't have more time to help just now.

Comment: Hi, yes, the simulation does what you describe.  And I've also updated my question to include an approach I had in mind.  Any suggested improvements would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: How does the bouncer admit people? If the bouncer admits people in the order of the line, I recall from my clubbin’ days that my group stuck together in line and would be somewhat likely to be admitted in tact. If people were admitted at random, my group probably would have been fragmented.

Comment: The form of your answer looks right: it's an application of the PIE.